# Getting parent function's variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

```js
function bodycreate(num)
{
   var ref = database.ref('190/ExerciseTable/'+num+'/');
   ref.on('value',gotdata,errData);
}

function gotdata(data)//passes firebase data
{
        var ex3=you.val();
 var sa3=Object.keys(ex3);
 var s3=sa3.length;
 console.log(s3);//prints count of child elements
        console.log(num);//Here I want to print the variable num
}
```

I want to display the variable num. How can I get it from the parent function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @31piy are you telling like making them global??. But I have tried it, It doesn't work.

Comment: There's no "parent/child" relation between the functions in your code, both functions are rather "siblings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One which I can quickly think is

```
function bodycreate(num)
{
   var ref = database.ref('190/ExerciseTable/'+num+'/');
   ref.on('value',
         function(data){
           gotdata(data, num)
         },errData);
}
```

And then change signature of `gotdata` to receive two arguments.